# How to install pip?

Tags: macos, pip

I am trying to install `pip` in Lion 10.7.
By typing

`sudo easy_install pip`

i get the following message:

`Searching for pip`

`Best match: pip 1.2.1`

`Processing pip-1.2.1-py2.7.egg`

`pip 1.2.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth`

`Installing pip script to /usr/local/bin`

`error: /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory`

I checked the path in `/usr/../bin/` and ther exists the `pip` directory.
How can i fix this?